# Unpivoting data using cross apply in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I want to do this query in Linq to Entities, is it possible?

```
select v.account, v.value
from t cross apply
     (values (t.AccountID1, t.value),
             (t.AccountID2, - t.value)
     ) v(account, value) ;
```

What this query does is take AccountID1 and AccountID2 which are columns and unpivot them into rows, I'd like to do this in LINQ to Entities as well.

TL;DR: I'm trying to convert columns into rows using LINQ to Entities

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Long answer: yes, but with [linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore). If you OK to work with third party extensions, I'll show sample.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this

```cs
var results =
    from t in t
    from v in new[] {
        new {account = AccountID1, value = t.value},
        new {account = AccountID1, value = -t.value}
    }
    select v;
```

If the query becomes untranslatable, you may need to pull it all back into the client and unpivot there, by changing the above to `from t in t.ToList()`

Comment: *If* it becomes untranslatable? Of course it does(just test it!). And pulling an entire table into memory is bad advice.

Comment: @GertArnold Depends on the provider, some can translate it. I didn't have access to Linq-to-Entities so couldn't test

Comment: I don't think any provider can translate this. They'd have to create value tuples from CLR objects. Never heard of an EF provider that does that. If you know more, please tell.